# Can 'unwind' be used in German in a sense that means 'to relax'?

Tags: english-to-german

I want to say *to unwind* in German and for it to mean *relax*. Is this a synonym of the word *over* in Germany too? Or is it only used literally, as in *to unwind a piece of string*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I am concerned, there is no figureatively corresponding word, which means to "unwind" something and at the same time to "relax".

"Unwind" in German means "Abwickeln" oder "Abspulen" and this is only used literally.

Concerning relaxation, in German, you would use, e.g., "entspannen", which means as much as "remove tension". This is not connected with the winding motion of unwind.

Comment: Thankyou so much!

Comment: Naja, bei gewickelten Federn, wie sie etwa in Fahrradbremsen oder Wäscheklammern vorkommen, entspricht das Entspannen aber dann doch einer Abwickelbewegung.

Comment: Sagst du dann “Die Wäscheklammer abwickeln” bzw. War das ein Scherz? Sonst kann ich noch einige andere Tätigkeiten die mit entspannen umschrieben werden können und so gar nichts mit einer Abwickelbewegung zu tun haben aufführen, würde aber wahrscheinlich die Verletzung verschiedener Regularien in Kauf nehmen müssen.